# How can I run javascript code after an item added or removed from an unlimited value field?

Tags: 7, entities, ajax

I am trying to add some js functionality to an unlimited value field in Drupal 7, it works on page load, but disappears after adding or removing an item, and I did not find a way to notify my code that the table is reloaded, and it is time to reinitialize those functions on the fields. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know how your code is, but did you try the live() (http://api.jquery.com/live/) method ?

Comment: I use this to add event listeners to the inputs, and it works, but I can't find a way to use it to run code immediately after loading, and I want to do that too.

Comment: You could check the ajaxComplete (http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) event, but be aware it's not element dependant but triggered on a global basis.

Comment: Might work as last resort, but it would interfere with other ajax calls (like, an autocomplete field on the same form).
Seeing how customizable other parts of Drupal are, it is hard to believe there is no 'official' way to do this.

Comment: If there is one, I don't know about it. Did you search d.o for this ? The last time I investigated, there was work going on for D8 about lazy loading and that kind if stuff, but I can't tell you more.

Comment: Could you put the re-init javascript in the field template?

Comment: please add some code or more description about your problem

Comment: GrayB: I tried that, with mixed results. Sometimes, the code ran as expected, sometimes nothing happened.

Finally, I scrapped the whole thing, and solved the problem without the built-in multivalue field.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer so other people in the community can benefit.  You can also then mark it as accepted to close this question!

Comment: I do not have that code anymore, but here is how it worked:
In the Drupal form API, I defined a single text field, which unpacked those values to multiple fields, and added the control buttons. On form submit, it built the single array from the values, and submitted that.
On server side, it required some additional processing, but that was necessary for other reasons as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [Drupal behavior](http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors). It will be attached to each field when the page loads as well as to new fields added after any ajax calls (adding or removing).

Here is a basic example that will log a click on the text boxes in the field `field_fieldname`

```
(function ($) {
  // Logclick is an arbitrary unique behavior name
  Drupal.behaviors.logclick = {
    // Context here allows your function to run on ajax calls
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      // Your custom jQuery goes here
      $(".field-name-field-fieldname input.form-text",context).once('logclick',function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
          console.log('text box clicked');
          return false;
        });
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

`logclick` can be changed to whatever you want to call your behavior.

Comment: I can not try this now (without rebuilding a similar environment again, and I do not want that now), but it seems to do what I needed, thanks! It might be useful next time.

Comment: I met a similar problem in D6, and this solution worked. Thanks again!